# expectation value of a specific distribution function

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value

for a random variable X with this distribution function : 
F(x) = \begin{cases}
0, & x < 0 \\
\frac{(x+1)}{4}\, & 0 \leq x < 1 \\
1, & x \geq 1
\end{cases}
i want to find the expectation value and i know it is 5/8 but i don't know how to solve it!

Comment: Do you know the definition of expectation for continuous random variables? This is just an application of that definition.

Comment: yes i know but i don't get 5/8

Comment: If you write your solution step by step, we can help you find where it goes wrong.

Comment: $E(X) =  \int_0^\infty (1-F(x))\,dx - \int_{-\infty}^0 F(x)\,dx$ for any random variable $X$ (provided the integrals converge).

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are possibly thrown off by the fact that $X$ is neither a discrete nor a continuous random variable. Note that $F(x)$ has jumps at $0$ and $1$, i.e., $X=0$ with probability $\dfrac{1}{4},$ and $X=1$ with probability $\dfrac{1}{2}.$ $X$ is continuous elsewhere. You can think of $X$ as

$$X=\begin{cases}
0 \hspace{2.5cm}\text{ with prob. }\dfrac{1}{4}
\\\text{Unif}(0,1) \hspace{1cm}\text{ with prob. }\dfrac{1}{4}
\\1 \hspace{2.5cm}\text{ with prob. }\dfrac{1}{2}.
\end{cases}$$

By linearity of expectation, $\mathbb{E}(X)=0\times \dfrac{1}{4}+\mathbb{E}(\text{Unif}(0,1))\times \dfrac{1}{4}+1\times \dfrac{1}{2}=0+\dfrac{1}{2}\times\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{1}{2}=\dfrac{5}{8}.$

In any case, as pointed out in the comments, you can use
$$\mathbb{E}(X)=\int_{0}^{\infty}(1-F(x))dx-\int_{-\infty}^{0}F(x)dx=\int_{0}^1\dfrac{3-x}{4}dx=\left[\dfrac{3x-x^2/2}{4}\right]_0^1=
\dfrac{5}{8}.$$

Comment: thank you!i didn't notice that X is a mixed random variable and got the wrong answer.

Comment: @jud you're welcome. If you think this answers your question, you can consider [upvoting](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) and [accepting](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) the answer.